# Setting Animation frame number without playing

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to set the animation frame without playing it currently i am doing this it work perfectly but can i make it possible without playing the animation?

```
GO.GetComponent<Animation>().Play("Start");
GO.GetComponent<Animation>()["Start"].time = ((1f / 30f) * 0);
GO.GetComponent<Animation>()["Start"].speed = 0;
```

Comment: You can try like this: `GO.GetComponent<Animation>().Play("Start", PlayMode.StopAll);`

Comment: i have tried this. actually I have lots of animation which are playing one an after. So if i play an animation then next will execute consequently. I want to prevent this behavior. Thats why searching a way to set the frame rate of an animation without playing that animation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My advice would be to create a new state that simply contain that one frame.

It is counter-intuitive to think of a state that is stuck on its first frame. It is like saying you are int eating state but only holding the fork without any movement. Something is not quite right in that statement.

So you'd rather have a Immobile state and then run it in loop. When you need to start doing other actions, then just switch as would.

Now if you want to start an animation at a specific position:

```
 animator.Play("AnimName",layer, normPosition);
```

Comment: Thanks for brilliant trick although it is not satisfying the question heading but its work for me so for future I am going to share my code which will save other as well. Thanks again.